# using diff/patch in windows, aka, "can't find file to patch at input line 4"

Tags: windows-7, diff, cvs, patch

I am using CVS and win7. I need to copy some changes from the trunk to a branch, so I thought I could just use "diff -ruN" to put the changes into a file, and then use "patch -i" to apply them to the branch.

So I saw [this page](http://jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html), and [this page](http://drupal.org/node/60179). I already had cygwin diff, so I got gnu patch [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm). I made two files

```
\test\mydir1\afile.txt
\test\mydir2\afile.txt
```

which have minor differences. Then I type

```
cd test
diff -ruN mydir1 mydir2 >test.patch
patch --dry-run -i test.patch
```

and the result is

```
can't find file to patch at input line 4
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
```

so I tried

```
patch --dry-run --verbose -p1 -i test.patch
```

and I get the same error. I tried a lot of other things for a long time with no success. Why is this so hard?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok here are the two things I needed to know, but were not documented anywhere

- diff output uses unix format, but patch requires dos format
- the default "strip" in patch is NOT -p0 like you might expect. It is -p1.

This works...

```
diff -ruN mydir1 mydir2 | unix2dos > test.patch
patch -p0 -i test.patch
```

You must convert to DOS line endings, and you must specify -p0. Otherwise the default is -p1. I hope this will help someone else.

Comment: Thanks a great deal for providing this answer for me! It works like my charm :)

Comment: I was also expecting -p0 to be the default. Manually specifying it fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have since learned more about CVS, so I don't use patch anymore. If you want to copy specific changes from one CVS branch to another, you can do it with [CVS UPDATE -j -j](http://cvsgui.sourceforge.net/howto/cvsdoc/cvs_5.html).  For example, suppose you change file1.cpp on the HEAD from 1.45 to 1.46. You can navigate to the branch and type

```
cvs update -kk -j 1.45 -j 1.46 file1.cpp
```

and it will copy the specified change from HEAD to branch.

If you want to copy changes from many files, you can use cvs rtag to create tags based on date (etc) and then use the tags in the update, such as

```
cvs update -kk -j tagBeforeChange -j tagAfterChange
```